# chrome.usb.getDevices cannot find CH340 (FTDI) serial adapter

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have arduino nano connected to computer, one use CH340 chip.
From chrome I can see serial port (from chrome.serial.getDevices) but I cannot find one from chrome.usb.getDevices. I'm looking for a way to get connection/disconnetion message.
It is possible because it's used in betaflight configurator but there is different processor.

```
manifest.json
"permissions": [
  "serial", "usb",
  {
  "usbDevices": [
      {
        "vendorId": 6790,
        "productId": 29987
      } 
  ]}
]

and js code
function onDeviceFound(devices) {
  this.devices=devices;
  if (devices) {
    if (devices.length > 0) {
      console.log("Device(s) found: "+devices.length);
      console.log(devices[0]);
    } else {
      console.log("Device could not be found");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Permission denied.");
  }
}
chrome.usb.getDevices({"vendorId": 6790, "productId": 29987}, onDeviceFound);
```

Comment: Information about serial port confirms that data are correct {displayName: "USB-SERIAL CH340", path: "COM3", productId: 29987, vendorId: 6790}

Comment: Chrome USB is finicky and requires a certain USB driver, I don't remember which exactly.